Unable to use Find My app
I am unable to use Find My Device app on my OnePlus 9 Pro. Even if I enable Find My Device under Settings > Google > Find My Device, the Find My app still asks me to turn on the service.
I have tried rebooting the phone, but it doesn't help. I have checked for the latest OS updates as well as Play Store updates, but looks like I am up-to-date.
Screenshot showing Find My Device is enabled:

But it still asks me to enable the Find My Device:

Any idea what can be done? Don't wish to format the phone though.
Thanks

Are the location services enabled on the device?

Yes, they are enabled.

How many Google accounts do you have logged in on that phone (see settings -> accounts)? One or more?

Looks like your device is already registered by Find My Device (shown as "This device"), so could you explain more about what you meant by "unable to use"? Is your device not shown on the Find My Device web? Can you tap your device in the app to show the device details like IMEI, and activation date, and to change the device name?

@Robert Initially there were 2 accounts logged in, and I was afraid that might be causing the issue. But then I removed my non-primary account, rebooted the phone, but that also didn't help.

@AndrewT. While I am able to track my phone, but I am not able to add any more devices to my Find Device app. Although I was able to add the same tracker to another Android device.
